# React CountDown renders other component every second

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I have created a countdown timer and then called it another component WordSearchContainer  along with RandomBoard.
**My problem is along with every countdown decrment,  it rerenders RandomBoard - **

I am not sure, what is wrong and how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**WordSearch.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'
import CountDown from './CountDown';
import WordSearchBoard from './RandomBoard';
// function WordSearch() {


const WordSearchContainer = forwardRef(({ timer, data, entryId, hours, minutes, seconds }, ref) => {

 
  
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [timeleft, settimeleft] = useState(timer)
    const [over, setOver] = useState(false);
  
    const [score, setscore] = useState(0)
    const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(true);

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (timer > 0) {
            if (timeleft === 0) {
                // console.log("TIME LEFT IS 0");
                settimeleft(0)
                UpdateQuizEntryTimerLeft()
                setTimeout(() => setShow(true), 1000)
            }

        }

    }, [timeleft])

 
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        UpdateTimerLeft() {
            UpdateQuizEntryTimerLeft()
            return true
        }

    }))


    return (
       <>
                {
                    (timer && isStarted) ? <CountDown hours={hours} minutes={minutes} seconds={seconds} settimeleft={settimeleft} timeleft={timeleft} className='text-center text-danger' extraclass="" over={over} setOver={setOver} /> : <></>
                }
                
            <WordSearchBoard   />

            </>
    )




});


WordSearchContainer.displayName = "WordSearchContainer"

export default WordSearchContainer
```

**CountDown.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';



function CountDown({ hours, minutes, seconds, settimeleft, timeleft, className, extraclass, over,
setOver }) {

    const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
    const [[h, m, s], setTime] = useState([hours, minutes, seconds]);
    const tick = () => {
        if (paused || over) return;
        if (h === 0 && m === 0 && s === 0) {
            setOver(true);
            settimeleft(0);

        } else {
            settimeleft(timeleft - 1)
            if (m === 0 && s === 0) {
                setTime([h - 1, 59, 59]);
            } else if (s == 0) {
                setTime([h, m - 1, 59]);
            } else {
                setTime([h, m, s - 1]);
            }
        }
        
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const timerID = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(timerID);


        
    });

// ${h.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:
  return (
      <div className={className}>
          {over ? <></> : <p className={`font-weight-bold ${extraclass}`}>{`Time Left ${m.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${s.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`}</p>}
          {over ? <span className='text-white bg-danger py-2 mb-2  px-2'>Time up </span> : ''}
         
      </div>
  )
}

export default CountDown;
```

**Randomboard.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'

 


function WordSearchBoard({setIsStarted}) {

 

    return (
        <div className='gameArea mx-4 p-2 row'>
           

            {
              
               Math.random(9,999)
            }





        </div>
    )




}

export default WordSearchBoard
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it is all states related to counter lies in wordsearch. And randomBoard doesn't dependent on any state whenever state updates in wordsearch component, it rerenders both components counter and randomBoard. Try to move and handle states in counter component.